# If I'm making a copy of an NSObject subclass, does its properties of type "UIViewAnimationOptions" and type BOOL need to be copied? If so, how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, copy-constructor, nsobject

I have my own NSObject subclass with which I'm implimenting the NSCopying protocol. In my `copyWithZone` method, I'm copying over the properties and values like

```
myCopy.boolProp = self.boolProp;
```

but I'm wondering how I'm supposed to copy over properties with type UIViewAnimationOptions and type BOOL given they're not objects with a copy method. If the properties' values are later changed on the copy, I DO NOT want them to change on the original.

How can I ensure that non-object values are copied, and not referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment is sufficient for copying primitive values like BOOL and enumeration values. The only way you *could* get a reference to them in Objective-C is by making a pointer to them and copying that.

In other words, your example code is fine.